# ARIMA, coefficients check

Tags: t-test, arima, regression-coefficients

I would appreciate if someone could check the mathematical equation for the seasonal ARIMA (4,1,3) x (1,1,1) period 12 that I wrote. I have done it this way, but I am not really sure if it correct is. Can someone check it and correct it? I would be graetfull.

$(1+0,6350877 B + 0.342846B^2 - 0.5634599B^3 - 0.0252533B^4)(1+0.0867653 B^{12}) (1-B) (1-B^{12}) YT= (1 + 0.1328264 B - 0.132815  B^2 – 1.000002 B^3)(1-1.177959 B^{12})E_t$

Should I drop non-significant coefficients and leave it this way?
$(1+0,6350877 B + 0.342846B^2 - 0.5634599B^3)(1-B) (1-B^{12}) Y_t=(1-1.177959 B^{12})E_t$

Here are my results:
[image]

Which formula will be better?
Thank you in advance.
Kind regards

Comment: The expression looks correct. But for safety, you should check the source of the table that you posted because sometimes ARIMA models are specified following a different convention for the sign of the coefficients.

Comment: As regards removing non-significant coefficients, in principle I wouldn't recommend it as a general practice. See some discussion about it [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117474/seasonal-adjustment-for-a-series-that-has-already-been-adjusted/117539#117539),
[here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101399/how-to-test-the-arima-coefficients), 
[here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123682/arma-parameters-estimation/123775#123775),
and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/107603/).